# CentOs CPU usage 100% by sync_supers

Tags: centos, cpu-usage

I see it in the `top -c`
[image]

Then I run `strace` of this process and see a lot of `select(8, [3], NULL, NULL, {0, 0})      = 0 (Timeout)`

[image]

What should I do next? How can I find the reason of this? Any help much appreciated

Comment: Notice how that process is running as user nobody and has a high PID? I'm almost certain that your server was compromised.

Answer (score 2):

Run `lsof -p 21078` and record the output. Kill the process. Delete the files associated with that process.

Since you have CentOS, you may want to find out how they got in. That's a deeper exercise beyond the scope of this question, but download and run `chkrootkit` and possibly verify your RPMs to start.

Comment: I did `lsof`, output below. Do you have ideas what it means? http://joxi.ru/nAyz0e0hjLj0rZ